# UINavigation Controller from scratch help

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

How do I create a NavigationController with a TableView inside of it from scratch (putting it into my existing project without using the template)? Can I do it with only one view controller and xib or will I more? Are there any tutorials someone can point me to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with or without a nib file.

I think you should watch the first 10 minutes of [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw)  !